Why do I get permission denied while deleting a file
I have a school project and I am getting an error from the remove function. It should be a simple function but I always get a "permission denied" error. I have checked that the file is not read only, etc.
This program is running on Windows 11.
Here is the function:
void deleteFile(const char* fileName) { 
    if (remove(fileName) == 0) {
         printf("File %s has been deleted!\n", fileName);
    }  
    else {
         perror("Error with file delete...");     
    }
}


Try compiling it and find out! You're much more likely to get answers if you provide a [mcve] -- syntactically valid code that we can copy and run locally to reproduce the problem you're asking about.

Sorry for bad explanation it is my first time using stack overflow. I now got error with file delete message after adding one perenthesis. I think that may be because file is opened all the time while program is running so it can't be removed?

Unrelated, you also shouldn't invent your own code formatting style completely different than the one used by millions of C programmers before you.

Only Windows complains about deleting a file that's open somewhere.  It matters which platform you're on.

How to I implement perror() to tell me where actually does it stop?

What operating system is this for?

I assume your "Permission denied" is for errno value EACCES. This could be due to lack of write permission on the directory containing the file, or lack of search permission in a component directory of the pathname, or you are on Windows and the file being removed is open, or you are on Windows and the file has read-only access.

I am on windows 11

Try to delete the file manually from the Windows Explorer and tell us what happens.

Which file exactly are you trying to delete? Did you open that file in another part of your code you didn't show? Please [edit] and show a [mcve].

Also show the filename and the current working directory.

Your code is probably trying to delete an open file.
#include <stdio.h> 

void deleteFile(const char* fileName) {
  if (remove(fileName) == 0) {
    printf("File %s has been deleted!\n", fileName);
  }
  else {
    perror("Error with file delete...");
  }
}

int main() {
  FILE* f = fopen("somefile", "w");
  if (f == NULL)
  {
    perror("File could not be created");
    return;
  }

  // do something with f

  // fclose(f);   // <<< uncomment this and the deletion should work
  deleteFile("somefile");
}

This codes produces following output:
Error with file delete...: Permission denied

If you uncomment the line // fclose(f);, the file will be closed and the file removal should work.

This is my suspicion too.
